# Hibernate FK to itself not on primary key

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I've got a table with the following structure:

```
NUMBER RECORD_ID - PK
STRING NAME
STRING SOME_OTHER_BS
NUMBER ID - the person id i need to group the records by
```

I've mapped the fields like this in my hibernate entity:

```
long id; // RECORD_ID
String name; // NAME
String someOtherBS; // SOME_THER_BS
long personId; // ID
```

Now the problem is I need to have a Set of elements with the same personId in the entity. I tried to do this:

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = MyEntity.class)
@JoinColumns( {
    @JoinColumn(name="`ID`", referencedColumnName = "`ID`")
} )
private Set<MyEntity> otherEntities;
```

But this gives me the following error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.sflpro.dto.MyEntity column: ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:681) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:703) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1294) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1736) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
>       ... 74 common frames omitted

So how can I accomplish this?

P.S.

This is a legacy database and changing it's design is a bureaucratic hassle so I'd prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
@JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="RECORD_ID")
```

Remember that your primary key is `RECORD_ID` and your foreign key is `ID`

Comment: sorry, but that's not what I want to do. I don't want the join working on my PK, I need a list of MyEntities with the same personId(ID) as my current record.